# What does 'spin' mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Bonaparte was a master of what we would now call spin, ...

The context can be found [here](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=8rzGxWUQiKkC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=Bonaparte%20was%20a%20master%20of%20what%20we%20would%20now%20call%20spin&source=bl&ots=xNkB5EbXgl&sig=bL-Y7W1e_2I47E5NAKxrloJwSho&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwioiPDYnKPQAhXCVxQKHSirDl0Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=Bonaparte%20was%20a%20master%20of%20what%20we%20would%20now%20call%20spin&f=false).

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary? I checked four reputable online dictionaries (Collins, Longman's, Oxford, Merriam-Webster) and found relevant definitions of **spin**, *noun* in all of them.

Comment: The closest definition I found: bias (in media). Do they mean something like manipulation of public opinion?

Answer (score 1):

It is [also called](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spin) *spin control*.

> the activity of trying to control the way something (such as an important event) is described to the public in order to influence what people think about it

Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spin%2Bcontrol)